# Extrair tag xml de uma coluna varchar(max)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-select

Olá,

tenho uma série de registros xml em uma coluna varchar(max) e preciso extrair a tag `<MT_USADA>16 MB</MT_USADA>`, por exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<consulta xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <MT_TOTAL>4 GB</MT_TOTAL>
    <MT_USADA>16 MB</MT_USADA>
</consulta>
```

Tentei de duas maneiras, porém funciona apenas em colunas xml

```
SELECT colunaxml.value('(/consulta/MT_TOTAL)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as teste from tabela
```

ou

```
SELECT colunaxml.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(max)') FROM tabela
```

tentei usar um CAST e CONVERT `SELECT CAST(colunaxml AS xml)` / `SELECT CONVERT(xml,colunaxml)`, mas não consegui combinar com `colunaxml.value()`

O resultado que espero é algo como

ID  |  memoria_usada

01  |  16 MB

**Edit:**
Consegui algo que traz bem o que eu preciso, mas não compreendi como colocar em um Select ... from tabela

```
declare @xml varchar(1000)    
SET @xml='<consulta xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <MT_TOTAL>4 GB</MT_TOTAL>
        <MT_USADA>16 MB</MT_USADA>
    </consulta>'

    select @xml,SUBSTRING (@xml,CHARINDEX('<MT_USADA>',@xml)+LEN('<MT_USADA>'),(CHARINDEX('</MT_USADA>',@xml)-(CHARINDEX('<MT_USADA>',@xml)+LEN('<MT_USADA>'))))
```

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui a resposta, funcionou assim:

```
select  
SUBSTRING (@coluna,CHARINDEX('<MT_USADA>', @coluna)+LEN('<MT_USADA>'),(CHARINDEX('</MT_USADA>', @coluna)-(CHARINDEX('<MT_USADA>', @coluna)+LEN('<MT_USADA>')))) FROM @tabela
```